# QCalendarWidget with date

Tags: c++, qt, datetime, widget

I want to have visual element that pop-ups on button press and allows user to choose date and time. Is it in Qt some visual widget like QCalendarWidget but also with time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Where have you see such pop-ups?*

*Hope, that it fits you problem.* You can use `QDateTimeEdit` with checked param `calendarPopup` -- and there you'll get date & time with calendar popup, and time editing possibility in one visual element.